# How to change the Botkit port?

Tags: botkit

I created a `Botkit` project. It runs on `port` 3000 by default. But there are already Nodejs projects created, and one of them uses `port` 3000. So how to change the port of the `Botkit` project ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can change the port by adding a `PORT` env variable.

Example if you start your project by doing: `node botkit.js`, change your script by : `PORT=3001 node botkit.js`.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: `'PORT' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne`